# how to add one text in center and another in bottom in flutter>

Tags: flutter

In below shown image one text is in middle and another one is in the bottom, how do I do it?

[image]

Comment: Present your best effort. With which problem are you stuck?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sharing example code to get this type of UI ,

```
Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        width: double.infinity,
        color: Colors.green,
        child: Stack(
          children: [
            Center(
              child: Container(child: Text("Middle Text")),
            ),
            Align(
              alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
              child: Container(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 20),
                  child: Text("bottom text")),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the simple implementation of your design, I prefer you to searching on youtube/any other learning platform for learning flutter

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        title: 'Flutter Demo',
        theme: ThemeData(
          primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        ),
        home: Scaffold(
          backgroundColor: const Color.fromARGB(255, 41, 120, 88),
          body: SafeArea(
            child: Container(
              child: Stack(
                children: [
                  Center(
                    child: Container(
                        child: const Text(
                      "Gets you Job.",
                      style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                          fontSize: 36),
                    )),
                  ),
                  Align(
                    alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                    child: Container(
                        child: const Text(
                      "c Intropros Technologies",
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.white,
                      ),
                    )),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
     );
   }
 }
```

[image]

there's a lot of learning platform right now, udemy, youtube, and you can read flutter documentation too.